# Need IDE suggestions for Chrome Extension project

Tags: ide, google-chrome-extension, projects-and-solutions

I currently use Programmer's Notepad for my Chrome Extension project. I like Programmer's Notepad, as it is simple to use and I don't need debugging features (Chrome has all that for me). However, I check the project into Subversion and it stores absolute paths, which will not allow other people to use it unless they use the same exact path.

I have Visual Studio 2010 at my disposal, but I haven't seen a useful way to use it. I have also heard of Aptana Studio, but I was discouraged from trying it out fully because it seemed too bloated for my needs.

What is a good IDE I can use for chrome extension development? The most important factor is good project support. Relative paths need to be stored in the project and it should keep files grouped together so I can work out of the IDE and not have to continuously open files in Windows Explorer.

Secondly good syntax highlighting and intellisense are ideal but I can live without it. Intellisense with jQuery and the built in Chrome Extension API are pluses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geany is a good very lightweight with project management and everything. Latest version also includes local intellisense for opened files and has very nice syntax highlighting and some other nice plugins.

Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper (to allow for the JS intellisense) works nice as well but it slightly bloated when it comes to just javascript extension development.

I would actually just recommend a lightweight editor such as Notepad++ or Vim/Emacs but it seems that your project may have grown too big for this so Geany would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Komodo Edit is free and seems to meet all of your requirements:

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

If you are willing to pay for it, the ActiveState (same people) Komodo IDE gets very good reviews:

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide/features